# Random persistent problems from PC where it crashes or doesn't BOOT up

Tags: display, crash

My PC randomly crashes since recently, but mainly after using something GPU intensive such as gaming or simple video playbacks. The display just goes black and loses signal, sometimes preventing a shutdown or restart.

just recently the same happened again but the beep sound when there's no RAM came up after the display crash. Sometimes the problem goes away for a while when I reseat the memory and it starts displaying the BOOT screen.

Interestingly the second PC also sometimes crashes which can be fixed by reseating the memory sticks. One time after the main PC crashed I removed the HDMI cable and found the connector still having some current, which makes me believe this could be an electrical issue. Does anyone know what to do in this situation?

Comment: You could try to measure voltages on PSU and check memory with Memtest 86

Comment: Make sure that all the devices you are using are all plugged into the same power strip, not even an outlet.  This just rules out a ground loop problem, where grounds can have a different voltage from different outlets.  We did have an AMD card that was at almost 100% GPU, and the fan would never stop running at 100% after going to 10% GPU, OR power-down/restart. Only was fixed by doing an image backup restore, so never figured out how it could store that crashed state with fan stuck at 100%. So mine was NOT a hardware problem--Very odd.

Comment: Your problem sounds like hardware.  However, in my case it obviously was not a hardware issue at all.  If the results of your heavy use and crash is somehow stored as mine was, somehow in the GPU's settings on the HD, even a power down won't clear the error.  To rule this out, only way I know is to back up a drive image when it is working and restore to a new drive, then put the old drive back in-use, and "break it". Next, reboot with the new drive and see it the problem is gone.  Then, look for what changed in the GPU settings.  --- Help anyone??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's hardware, since recently there has been no boot up problems since I opened the case and tightened the screws with just my hands (which means it's not as tight as before) but it did crash soon after when I was playing WWE 2K16 but it's been mostly okay since then.

What leads me to think it might be a power problem is that the 2nd pc is giving the ram missing beep again.. and it's mostly random but I will try the tests to see if anything comes up.